# eclipes tomcat 404 error could not find java file

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat

can anyone help me please. I'm using eclipse IDE and apache tomcat 9.0.12. I'm trying to do my assigment where we have to create html and java file. My html file works just fine but the problem occurs when im trying to get the data from java file. I already watch youtube and google but their problem is different than mine. I dont have typo or any simple problem .. I think it is a path problem but i don't know how. it seems like eclipes coudlnt find where my java file located.[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kklPV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ7Ed.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbOZl.png)

i trie to check typo, change localhost path , no different

Comment: Why is your servlet written to forward incoming requests to an invalid URL for its source file (which you usually wouldn't publish)?

Comment: May i know what you mean by that.. our assigment need us to retrieve what written in the java from the html file

Comment: Is the assignment about showing the Java source file itself, because that's generally not a useful thing to do. You've also messed up your project's Java Build Path. As shown, the Source Folder should be `src/main/java`, not `src` itself.

Comment: "/IntroToServlet1/JavaResources/src/main/java/welcome.java" is this what you mean? I still cannot open the java file .. or do you mean the path on the menu.. it automatically goes under src .. how can I change it?